# How to transform arbitrary tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am having trouble understanding this and I have consulted several sources, but they all have very convoluted explanations. The one I have found the most useful is Frankel's The Geometry of Physics, but frankly I still have trouble understanding it. I believe that my main problems with all these explanations is the cumbersome notation with tons and tons of indices.

Could anyone explain to me how change of bases works on tensors please?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the point you're finding tricky?

Comment: It would depend on the source where I am trying to learn it from. In the case of Frenkel, he explains it in terms of the components of the tensor, but since this tensor is arbitrary, the way of expressing it seems odd. I have a general problem understanding it. For example, I expect the Jacobian matrices to show up somewhere according to how many dual spaces and vector spaces we are talking about on our tensor.

Comment: Yes, they show up either right-side-up or upside-down, once for each index. :)